# Iterate and append the value in JSON in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to iterate and append the `QId` and `Answer` from the payload, desired output would be like `12|Yes&&13|Yes&&14|Yes&&15|Yes&&16|Yes&&17|Yes&&18|Yes&&19|Yes&&`.

I have tried to get only `12|Yes&&` and `13|Yes&&` separately. All I wanted is to concatenate `QId` and `Answer` before it saves to the database. How could I achieve this

`Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'` this line which append the values

payload

```
0: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 150…}
1: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 151…}
2: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 152…}
3: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 153…}
4: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 154…}
5: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 155…}
6: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 156…}
```

What I tried

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
   
  if request.method == 'POST': 
    
    data = []
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for ran in request.data:
        auditorid =ran.get('AuditorId')
        print('SaveUserResponse auditorid---', auditorid)
        ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
        qid = ran.get('QId')
        answer = ran.get('Answer')
        sid =  ran.get('SID')
        print('sid--', sid)
        TicketType = ran.get('TicketType')
        TypeSelected = ran.get('TypeSelected')
        agents = ran.get('Agents')
        supervisor = ran.get('Supervisor')
        Comments = ran.get('Comments')
        action = ran.get('Action')
        subfunction = ran.get('AuditSubFunction')
        region = ran.get('AuditRegion')
        
        //Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'
        for qid in Qstans:
          Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'
          print(Qstans)
        
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@agents=%s,@supervisor=%s,@ticketid=%s,@Qstans=%s,@sid=%s,@TicketType=%s,@TypeSelected=%s, @Comments =%s, @action=%s, @subfunction=%s, @region=%s',
         (auditorid,agents,supervisor,ticketid, Qstans,sid, TicketType, TypeSelected, Comments, action, subfunction,region))
        result_st = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in result_st:
            row = row[0]
    return Response({0:{'Status':row}})
```

Comment: Your `for row` loop overwrites the `row` value each time.  Did you intend to concatenate all of those results into a single value?

Comment: Could you pls show the code  @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try "&&".join([f"p['Answer']|p['Qid']" for p in payload])

Comment: I have tried `Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'.join([str(qid)+'|'+(answer) for ran in request.data]) print(Qstans)` but its printing the same 'qid' and 'answer' `159|Yes&&159|Yes&&159|Yes&&159|Yes&&159|Yes&&159|Yes&&159|Yes&&159|Yes&&159|Yes&&159|Yes`

Comment: qid and answer have the same value in the list inside the join. Replace str(qid) with str(ran["qid"]) and see if it improves